# how to check in request Column is available or not Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose-schema

how to check if in request **Column "Status"** is available or not because when i check if(Job.Status){ console.log('in statusbody');} its show error when Status Column not available

> ReferenceError: Job is not defined

NODEJS//

```
  export function update(req, res) {
  var delta = checkcolumn( req.body);
}
function checkcolumn(Job) {  
 if(Job.Status)
{ 

console.log('in statusbody');
}

}
```

requestbody//

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("587244cf554a2515404de90d"),
        "Status" : {
            "updated_datetime" : ISODate("2017-01-08T13:55:27.539Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("587244cf554a2515404de90c"),      
            "total" : 2
},
  "description" : "",
    "updated_by" : ""
    }
```

Comment: If Job is not defined, the error is not with the Status field.  You should provide a code sample that replicates the error.

Comment: how to check column available or not

Comment: Questions about an error in your code need to include the actual code that causes the error, not just your data.  Then, we can help you very specifically (like in minutes) rather than trying to guess what your code is doing. You can use the "edit" link to modify your question to add the relevant code.

Comment: i edit my post....

Comment: @jfriend00 please check above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Job` is not defined, then that's because `req.body` is not defined when you pass it to `checkcolumn()`.  To fix the root of the problem, you will have to check on the request that is calling `update` and find out why `req.body` is `undefined`.  Perhaps you don't have the right middleware installed that sets `req.body` or perhaps you're using it incorrectly.  We'd have to see more of your code that calls `update()` to know what to advise there.

If you also want to protect `checkcolumn()` from throwing an error, you can have it check it's incoming parameter like this:

```
function checkcolumn(Job) {  
   if (Job && Job.Status) { 
       console.log('in statusbody');
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)